# How to add same strip ‣ repeat value to many objects at the same time in the nonlinear animation tool?

Tags: animation

I just want to add the same value to the repeat parameter at the same time to avoid the "copy-paste on by one" process.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Select all the strips, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> when clicking on the *Repeat* value, type the value.